# change <li> background when hover a

Tags: html, css

i have this menu:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AMORTECIMENTO</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

the normal apearance:

[image: normal apearance]

and this is the apearance when users hover the menu:

[image: :hover apearance]

So, i dont know how to setup the css, assuming i have biggest names on menu like: "AMORTECIMENTO"

Any tips??

i have tried this, but on small names, the menu is cutting the background...

```
.nav ul li a{
    display:block;
    font-size:15px;
    color:#000;
    padding:5px 7px;
    background:transparent;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.nav ul li:hover{
    background:url(../imagens/bola_fundo_menu.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

My intention is, when user hover the menu item, on the `<li>` background, apear the basketball, and on `<a>` tag, the background is going to #FFF but i have small and big names on menu, so i can't set width of `<li>` and `<a>` tags... i think

Comment: Can you clarify the problem and the desired look?

Comment: You should clarify your intentions better,i have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve

Comment: look at here: http://www.alsite.com.br/mvp/modelo.html - and the desired look is: http://www.alsite.com.br/mvp/example.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick example using pseudo-elements: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iwerJ

Using the exact HTML you originally posted, with CSS like this:

```
.nav { 
  background: #CCC; 
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 48px; 
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 90%;
}

.nav ul:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: block; 
}

.nav ul li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul li:hover:after {
    /* Replace background with image */
    background: #abc123;
    /* Optionally remove radius */
    border-radius: 30px;

    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin-top: -30px; 
    margin-left: -30px;
    height: 60px; width: 60px;
}

.nav a {
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 180%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
    .nav li:hover a { background: #FFF; }
```

Comment: I know it will work in IE9, however older IE's don't support pseudo-elements. This can be remedied with Dean's IE9.js - http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ or alternatively, using span's inside of the li's (after the <a>) instead of :after.

Answer (score 2):

Just set a hover background. Eg:

```
div.nav li:hover{
  background-image: url('basketball.jpg');
}
```

EDIT:
You've got a lot more issues than just a background image...

- You need to vertically center your nav text set a min-width for the
  nav cells so that the left and right of the ball aren't cut off
- set a solid white background for the anchor tag so the text is actually visible on hover
- set a z-index for the anchor tags that's greater
  than the center image so that they are all clickable (right now you
  can't click the link to the right of the center)

Good luck. I can't write all of that code out for you, but that should send you in the right direction.

Comment: look at here: alsite.com.br/mvp/modelo.html - and the desired look is: alsite.com.br/mvp/example.jpg

Comment: ok.. one last tip direction: what i need to when users hover the li, the white background is set to anchor tag? need to setup the anchor tag width an height equal the `<li>`?

Comment: You could implement that in a number of different ways. You're probably better off not using the anchor tag for the white background. You make a good point. There are ways to make it work, but not elegantly. You could add a paragraph tag inside the anchor and then set `display:inline-block;` and size it. That's one option.

Answer (score 0):

on your nav class all you have to do is write your css like this:

```
.nav ul li:hover
{ 
background-image:url('yourimage.jpg');
}
```

Comment: This is going to put a background across the entire `.nav`, which doesn't look like what they're wanting.

Comment: yes edited my answer,even tho i can't seem to figure out clearly what he is asking

Comment: look at here: alsite.com.br/mvp/modelo.html - and the desired look is: alsite.com.br/mvp/example.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To fix the cut-off images, you can simply put a `min-width` on your `.nav li` elements. Make sure the value is at least as wide as your background images.

You'll probably also want to add `text-align: center`.